# ¿Como correjir el Error al instala el editor sublime text desde repositorios ppa en las distribuciones Linux Mint o Lubuntu?

Tags: linux

Poseo el siguiente problema intento instalar el editor sublime text desde repositorios ppa: de la siguiente manera

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3 o sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
```

En las distribuciones  Lubuntu no me permite agregar los repositorios, ademas cuando lo hago por la distribucion de Linux Mint despues de agregarlo y ejecutar el comando sudo apt-get update me enseña el siguiente error

```
E: Some Index files to download
```

y por ende no me permite instalar el editor, pero cuando lo realizo desde la distribución de Ubuntu o Elementary os no me genera ese problema

Comment: A ver si me entero. ¿ Estas preguntando el porqué un `ppa` con paquetes para una determinada distro, no funciona en otras ?

Comment: Si , exacto a eso me referia